# why model.set(..) replace multiple records at a time using backbone.js?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have one problem which is related to saving records from edit mode. 
**Scenario:**

- Click on edit (first records), it will load selected model data in
  edit mode panel.
- Update any value in textbox
- Click on save, it will save successfully and refresh view.
- Click on edit (second records(, it will load selected model data in
  edit panel.
- Update any value in textbox
- Click on save, it will save successfully and refresh view
  But the problem is It will replace updated model value with Row1 and Row2. I would like to update only selected row. What was wrong in this code.

  ```
   window.App = { Models: {}, Collections: {}, Views: {}, Helper: {} }
                   App.Helper.getFormsValue = function (form) {
                       var newName = form.find('.name').val();
                       var newAge = form.find('.age').val();
                       var newOccupation = form.find('.occupation').val();
                       return { name: newName, age: newAge, occupation: newOccupation };
                   }
  ```

**Model and Collection**

```
App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: { name: '', age: 0, occupation: '' }
            });
            App.Collections.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: App.Models.Person
            });
```

**Add Person**

```
App.Views.AddPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '#addPersonWrapper',
                events: {
                    'click .add': 'addPersonForm',
                    'click .save': 'addPerson'
                },
                addPersonForm: function (e) {
                    $(e.target).hide();
                    this.$el.find('.addPerson').show();
                },
                addPerson: function () {
                    var form = this.$el;
                    form.find('.addPerson').hide();
                    form.find('.add').show();
                    var person = new App.Models.Person(App.Helper.getFormsValue(form));
                    this.collection.add(person);
                }
            });
```

**Edit Person**

```
App.Views.EditPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.editPersonWrapper',
                template: template.get('editTemplate'),
                initialize: function () {
                    this.$el.show();
                    this.rentder();
                },
                events: {
                    'click .save': 'savePerson'
                },
                rentder: function () {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                },
                savePerson: function () {
                    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
                    var form = this.$el;
                    this.model.set(App.Helper.getFormsValue(form));
                    this.$el.hide();
                }
            });
```

**Person View**

```
App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'tr',
                template: template.get('listTemplate'),
                initialize: function () {
                    this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
                    this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
                    this.on("edit", function (view) {
                        var editperson = new App.Views.EditPerson({ model: view.model });
                    }.bind(this));
                },
                events: {
                    'click .edit': 'editPerson',
                    'click .delete': 'deletePerson'
                },
                render: function () {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                    return this;
                },
                editPerson: function () {
                    this.trigger("edit", this);
                },
                deletePerson: function (e) {
                    this.model.destroy();
                },
                remove: function () {
                    this.$el.remove();
                }
            });
```

**People View**

```
App.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '#personList',
                initialize: function () {
                    this.collection.on("add", this.addPerson, this);
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function () {
                    this.collection.each(this.addPerson, this);
                },
                addPerson: function (person) {
                    var personView = new App.Views.Person({ model: person });
                    this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
                }
            });
```

**Default Data**

```
 var peopleCollection = new App.Collections.People([
                { name: 'Imdadhusen', age: 31, occupation: 'M.C.A.' },
                { name: 'Manindar', age: 27, occupation: 'B.E.I.T.' },
                { name: 'Kuber', age: 32, occupation: 'M.S.C.I.T.' },
                { name: 'Rashidali', age: 5, occupation: 'S.K.G' }]);
            var addPerson = new App.Views.AddPerson({ collection: peopleCollection });
            var peopleView = new App.Views.People({ collection: peopleCollection });
```

**HTML**

```
   <table border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 180px">Name</th>
                <th style="width: 50px">Age</th>
                <th style="width: 120px">Occupation</th>
                <th style="width: 50px"></th>
                <th style="width: 50px"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="personList">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="addPersonWrapper">
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="left">
                <input class="add" type="button" value="Add Person" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="addPerson">
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="left">Person Name</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name of the person" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearall"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="left">Person Age</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age of the person" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearall"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="left">Person Occupation</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input class="occupation" type="text" placeholder="Occupation of the person" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearall"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="left">
                    <input class="save" type="button" value="Save Person" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearall"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editPersonWrapper">
    </div>
```

**List Template**

```
 <script id="listTemplate" type="text/template">
        <td><%= name %></td>
        <td><%= age %></td>
        <td><%= occupation %></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </script>
```

**Edit Template**

```
 <script id="editTemplate" type="text/template">
        <h3>Edit Person</h3>
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="left">Person Name</div>
            <div class="right">
                <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name of the person" value="<%= name %>" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="left">Person Age</div>
            <div class="right">
                <input class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age of the person" value="<%= age %>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="clearall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="left">Person Occupation</div>
            <div class="right">
                <input class="occupation" type="text" placeholder="Occupation of the person" value="<%= occupation %>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="clearall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="left">
                <input class="save" type="button" value="Save Person" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearall"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Can any body help me to finding the cause of the problem. Any comment and suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're not removing your edit view when the user clicks on save. I didn't really look into your HTML, but the problem seems to be that all your edit views (I say all because you don't remove them, so they accumulate) share the same element. So when the user clicks to save, all your edit views catch the click event, and therefore apply the modifications to their own model.

For a solution, either remove your edit views once they're no longer used (`this.remove();` will do the trick, except that you'll have to deal with the fact that it removes your element), either use a single edit view (that would certainly require you to change more code).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried as per your suggestion but not able to edit second time any row due to view is unavailable after first time load

Comment: What solution did you try? The first? Did you make sure to take care of the element problem (the fact that it will be removed, so you had better make the view create its own element)?

Comment: Again thanks for your valuable suggestion. Do you have any alternate solution because i am very new in backbone.js framework. my vote +1

Comment: @imdadhusen I can't give a lot more information if I don't know what you tried :) Could you make an edit posting the changes you made (only the changes, you already posted enough code :))